# Cannot get my Query to execute in my DAO. Always returns null

Tags: java, sql-server, service, dao, dto

I had a small issue updating a query to link with my DAO.

Here is my Query:

```
String PROJECT_ID_QUERY_BY_RAB_WWID = "SELECT PR.ID FROM PR "
       + "LEFT OUTER JOIN PROJECT ON PR.PROJECT_ID = PROJECT.ID "
       + "LEFT OUTER JOIN TW_V_WWID ON PR.ID = TW_V_WWID.PR_ID "
       + "LEFT OUTER JOIN PR_STATUS_TYPE ON PR_STATUS_TYPE.ID = PR.STATUS_TYPE "
       + "LEFT OUTER JOIN TW_V_SITE_NAME_S ON PR.ID = TW_V_SITE_NAME_S.PR_ID "
       + "WHERE PROJECT.NAME = 'Site Lead' " 
       + "and TW_V_WWID.S_VALUE = (SELECT PERSON_RELATION.S_EXTERNAL_ID FROM TW_V_ROLES_APPROVED_BY " 
       + "left outer join person_relation on tw_v_roles_approved_by.id = person_relation.id "
       + "WHERE TW_V_ROLES_APPROVED_BY.PR_ID IN ?) and "
       + "(TW_V_SITE_NAME_S.S_VALUE IN (SELECT TW_V_SITE_NAME.S_VALUE FROM TW_V_SITE_NAME "
       + "left outer join tw_v_site_name_s on tw_v_site_name_s.pr_id = tw_v_site_name.pr_id "
       + "where tw_v_site_name.pr_id in ?) or tw_v_site_name_s.s_value = 'ALL SITES') "
       + "and PR_STATUS_TYPE.NAME = 'Approved Site Lead Permissions'";
```

As you can see there are two ?. These two ? are actually going to be the same.

This is my DAO class to call this Query:

```
public Integer getProjectID(Integer UA_PrID)
            throws SQLException, IOException {

        Integer prId = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(QueryConstants.PROJECT_ID_QUERY_BY_RAB_WWID);
            ps.setLong(1, UA_PrID);
            ps.setLong(2, UA_PrID);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                prId = rs.getInt("ID");
            }
        } finally {
            DaoUtil.cleanUp( ps, rs);
        }
        return prId;
    }
```

As you can see my PS statements are the same.

I make this call in my Service class to the DAO method:

```
Integer prId = userAccessVerificationDAO.getProjectID(wsdlDtoList.get(0).getPrId());
```

where wsdlDtoList.get(0).getPrId() is an integet value in my DTO class.

Everytime I try and debug this code I get to the DAO file and step over and I notice it skips this line everytime in the DAO:

```
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

I know I am missing something small here. A second set of eyes on this would be great. Please let me know if more information is required in order to solve this minor issue. I thank you all in advance for you input and help.

Here is the larger portion of the service class:

```
Integer prId = userAccessVerificationDAO.getProjectID(wsdlDtoList.get(0).getPrId());

        if (prId == null) {
            verificationResponse = new VerificationResponseDto();
            verificationResponse.setErrorType(ErrorConstants.VERIFICATION_ERROR_TYPE);
            verificationResponse.setErrorCode(ErrorConstants.FAILURE_ERROR_CODE);
            verificationResponse.setErrorMessage(ErrorConstants.NO_PR_ID_ERROR);
            logger.error(ErrorConstants.NO_PR_ID_ERROR);
            verificationResponseDtoList.add(verificationResponse);
            return verificationResponseDtoList;
```

Basically it returns null everytime. I manually ran this query in sqldeveloper and it does return a valid prID.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide exception stack trace?

Comment: @ Utkarsh Actually it does cause an error. The value of prId in the service class always returns null when I know its not supposed to. If you see above in the original question I have added the portion of what happens in the service class. Please see above.

Comment: Put a catch block before finally and print the stack trace. Provide the stack trace with your question

Comment: @Utkarsh Sorry for this question because I am a bit new to programming but doesn't the stacktrace only show the errors or trace of errors? If this is the case then I would have to reply that it does not result in an error. It just results in a null value returning everytime. I actually to have a catch statement that catches all exceptions and prints the stacktrace but it never gets to this catch block because there is no error.

Comment: As you mentioned, executeQuery is skipped during runtime. Code cannot skip lines unless there is an exception in previous lines. Try this : try { ps = conn.prepareStatement(QueryConstants.PROJECT_ID_QUERY_BY_RAB_WWID); ps.setLong(1, UA_PrID); ps.setLong(2, UA_PrID); rs = ps.executeQuery(); while (rs.next()) { prId = rs.getInt("ID"); } } catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); logger.error(e);}

Comment: How are you initializing conn object ? Can you put logs and check whether its not null ?

Comment: Catch block given in comment will catch all kinds of exceptions not only SQLException. So, we will get more information about the error to debug this.

Comment: Ok I understand. Let me recreate the error now.

Comment: @Utkarsh  Let me ask you a question. I added this catch block like you said and now it works with no issues. I find this kind of strange. This should not be the expected result right? I mean I just added what you told me above.

Comment: What do you mean by it works ?Is it returning prId now ? Yes, its strange

Comment: Yes. It is returning a PRid now. I am going to run this in debug and see what it is doing at this point. I wish I could share the screen with you to show you. lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84129/discussion-between-sonny-and-utkarsh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind the executeQuery getting skipped is because of exception occurring in previous line of code.

In your method, conn object is not initialized(this may be the issue). Also, add a catch block to log the error.